# MongoDB Aggregation for Time Series data

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, time-series, aggregation-framework

I have following document structure (events collection) for a time series data. I have decided this structure based on the article at https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports-mmapv1/

```
{
    "_id" : "06062017/cpu",
    "metadata" : {
            "host" : "localhost",
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-06-09T11:18:56.120Z"),
            "metric" : "cpu"
    },
    "hourly" : {
            "0" : {
                    "total" : 2,
                    "used" : 1
            },
            "1" : {
                    "total" : 3,
                    "used" : 2
            }
    },
    "minute" : {
            "0" : {
                    "0" : {
                            "total" : 9789789,
                            "used" : 353
                    },
                    "1" : {
                            "total" : 0,
                            "used" : 0
                    }
            },
            "1" : {
                    "0" : {
                            "total" : 0,
                            "used" : 0
                    },
                    "1" : {
                            "total" : 234234,
                            "used" : 123
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

Now I am trying to get the average cpu used from minutes and store it for hourly. Aggregation and map functions work well on Lists and arrays, I could not get the average per hour from minutes as well as I would like to get average per day as well.

I am using java as programming language. Is is better to calculate with in the application or with the aggregation framework?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The point pf a "pre-aggregated" structure is that you are meant to write to it and `$inc` values as you go along. That's why there are all the keys. It's also pretty horrible to do aggregations on later. So if all your data is only going into "minuites", then you are doing it wrong. To use the aggregation framework and traverse named keys you need at least MongoDB 3.4. Otherwise you would need mapReduce to traverse keys and aggregate.

Comment: Thank you Neil. We are still in the initial stages and flexible to make any structure changes. Idea is to store the cpu/memory stats per minute. We have a dashboard to display the stats monthlydaily/hourly/minute. What could be a better structure to achieve this.

Comment: The best way is to write the "hourly" at least at the same time as writing the minute. The document should probably be daily or even hourly as depends on the needs. By the same token you might even do daily and monthly to separate documents and collections as well, and also realize you do not **need** to do all of it in real time, and you can "message queue" operations and write latter. It's a really broad subject that you should research further. All this question is going to attract is silly attempts at writing a query to total for you. As you scale that is going to be useless.